# Image filename and path validation is not working in Firefox but working in Chrome

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, firefox

This image filename and path validation code works in Chrome but not in Firefox. It shows a validation error even if I upload a correct image file. Can anyone make this code work in Firefox?

```js
function add_img(f) {
  z = f;
  img_title = $('#img_title' + f + '').val();
  img_path = $('#img_path' + f + '').val();
  img_desc = $('#img_desc' + f + '').val();
  if (img_title == '' || img_path == '') {
    alert('Please upload a valid image with title.');
    return false;
  }
  var uploadcontrol = img_path;
  var reg = /^(([a-zA-Z]:)|(\\{2}\w+)\$?)(\\(\w[\w].*))+  (.jpeg|.JPEG|.gif|.GIF|.png|.PNG|.jpg|.JPG)$/;
  if (uploadcontrol.length > 0) {
    //Checks with the control value.
    if (!reg.test(uploadcontrol)) {
      alert("Only jpg,jpeg,gif,png files are allowed!");
      return false;
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: What's the error in Firefox?

Comment: it shows validation error even if we upload correct image file.

Comment: What's the exact file name you test with? Also from your code I can't tell what `f` is supposed to be.

Comment: sample.JPG  , home.PNG

Comment: f contains image count

Comment: I'm not sure if you can actually use `{number}` in a regexp inside the group it's referencing. Perhaps you should consider re-writing your regexp with that in mind.

Comment: I have improved the code formatting a bit, added a couple of tags relevant to the question and removed the language name from title as it is not required. I have also included the words *filename and path* in title because the code is more about file name + path validation than image validation.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't think there is a difference in regex implementation across browsers. The possibility could be that you are not getting the full path to check against in Firefox and are getting it in Chrome.
You can try to `console.log(uploadcontrol)` to check the path that is received in the two browsers. May be firefox doesn't give the drive letter that you expect it to and hence it doesn't pass the regex test.

Comment: I debugged via console.log(uploadcontrol).You are right.I got only file name in Firefox.

Answer (score 0):

For security reasons the browsers wont show the actual path.But chrome returns c:fakepath/  something like that.So that wont affect the validation.But Firefox only returns the file name.So i validate file name only instead of path.That works both browsers.

```
var uploadcontrol = img_path.split(/(\\|\/)/g).pop(); //code to get file name from path
var reg =  /^([a-zA-Z0-9\s_-])+(.jpeg|.JPEG|.gif|.GIF|.png|.PNG|.jpg|.JPG)$/;
```